# Merging postgres data

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have data in two postgresql databases that needs to be merged into 1.  Just to be clear, both databases have "good" data in them from a certain date that needs to be combined.  This isn't merely appending the data from one into another. In other words, let's say that table foo has an serial id field.  Both databases have a foo with ID=5555 and both values are valid (but different).  So, the target database's foo keeps 5555 and the new record should get added with a new ID of nextval(foo_id_seq).

So, it's a big mess.

My thoughts are to create a tmp schema in the target db and to copy the needed data from source db.  Then I need to essentially "upsert" the data.  New records get inserted with new ideas (and foreign keys updated) and records that exist in both dbs get updated.

I don't believe there is a tool that will help me with this.

My questions.

How best to handle generating the new id?  I know I could do it via selects and just leaving out the id column, but that's a lot of typing and would be slow.  My thinking is to create a temporary trigger for these tables that will override the id supplied when doing an insert.

Finally notes:

- Both databases are offline.  And I'm the only one that can get to them.
- Both database have the exact same schema
- Target database is 9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using something like:

```
INSERT INTO A(id, f1, f2)
SELECT nextval('A_seq'), tmp_A.f1, tmp_A.f2
FROM tmp_A
WHERE tmp_A.id IN (select A.id FROM A);

INSERT INTO A(id, f1, f2)
SELECT tmp_A.id, tmp_A.f1, tmp_A.f2
FROM tmp_A
WHERE tmp_A.id NOT IN (select A.id FROM A);
```

The idea - use one `INSERT .. SELECT ..` to insert the data with conflicts in id fields and other `INSERT .. SELECT ..` to insert the data without the conflict.

Or simply generate new `id` for every inserted record:

```
INSERT INTO A(id, f1, f2)
SELECT nextval('A_seq'), tmp_A.f1, tmp_A.f2
FROM tmp_A;
```

Comment: Yes; I understand I can do the select.  But, some of the tables have 50 columns.  I'm trying to avoid spending the rest of the day typing out insert/selects for all of the tables.

Comment: @DavidS You can generate queries dynamicly using [`pg_tables`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-tables.html) and [`pg_attribute`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html) tables.